# Checkbox filtering in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-filter

Having food items in a list of json, i want to filter out values from two checkbox using angularjs

[MY demo Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/Z208XZUQXqFw0K705AHc/)

Comment: could you be more specific what you need to actually do it

Comment: have to do dynamic filtering using two checkbox in  angulrjs

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

```
    $scope.CheckCheckbox = function (event,catName) {
        if(event)
        {
            angular.forEach($scope.get_listing, function (value, key) {
                angular.forEach(value.cat_name, function (v1, k1) {

                    if(v1==catName)
                    {
                        alert();
                    }
                });

            });

        }
    }
```

Comment: can you provide a plunker or jsfiddle ?

Comment: its not completed yet :

Comment: if we select more than one value means it"s not updating

Comment: because its not completed yet. ok give me few minutes i will complete it for you

Comment: Hello  sorry it takes time more then it expected. i done filtering for Category.